# How to manage security with One2many fields in Odoo?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, security, odoo, odoo-8

I have a doubt about security groups in Odoo 8, I will show a simple example to make it more understandable:

I have created two new models, **Mother** and **Child**. The relationship between them is that a mother can have several children, but a child will only have one mother. Therefore, we have an `One2many` field pointing to **Child** (named `child_ids`) in **Mother**, and a `Many2one` pointing to **Mother** (named `mother_id`) in **Child**.

Now, I have an user who can create some children, but not mothers. When he creates a child, he will only be able to select between a mother already created by other users with more privileges.

**The problem**

When this user creates the child, a security error raises telling that the user belongs to a group which cannot modify the **Mother** model. I think this is due to that when a child is created, the field `child_ids` of **Mother** is automatically modified.

**Temporal solution**

For the moment I have solved this giving writing permissions in **Mother** model to the group of the mentioned user. Because of this, when the user opens the form to create a child and selects a mother in `mother_id`, the open and edit icon is shown beside it. If the user clicks on it, he can modify the mother freely, which I do not want. I have hidden that icon, but due to this nobody can modify the mother from here, which I do not want neither. In addition to this, if the field `mother_id` appeared in other part which I did not know, the open and edit icon would not even be hidden.

**Note**

In the real case, I have not even created the field `child_ids` in **Mother**, I mean, I have only declared the Many2one `mother_id` in **Child**, but it seems that the program knows that an `One2many` field should exist in **Mother**, so I get the error mentioned above if I do not modify the writing permissions.

I have simplified my code and the problem is still there. Below you can read the whole code, I do not have anymore. If I remove the line `related='mother_id.is_a_good_mother',` from the field `has_a_good_mother` of **Child**, the ORM method write of Mother is not called (which is what I need).

Can anyone help me? Do you know how to achieve my purpose?

**Python code**

```
class mother(models.Model):
    _name = 'mother'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', size=64, required=True)
    is_a_good_mother = fields.Boolean(string='Is a good mother?')

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        _logger.info('I DO NOT KNOW WHY WHEN CREATING A CHILD THIS ORM '
                     'METHOD IS BEING EXECUTED, RECEIVING THE KEY '
                     'is_a_good_mother')
        return super(mother, self).write(vals)


class child(models.Model):
    _name = 'child'

    mother_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mother',
                                string='Mother', ondelete='cascade')
    has_a_good_mother = fields.Boolean(
        string='Does the child have a good mother?',
        related='mother_id.is_a_good_mother',
        related_sudo=True)

    @api.one
    def create_child(self):
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close',
        }
```

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="child_create_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">child.create.form</field>
            <field name="model">child</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="A child">
                    <group>
                        <group col="2">
                            <field name="id" invisible="1" />
                            <field name="mother_id" required="1" options="{'no_open': True}" />
                        </group>
                        <group col="2">
                            <field name="has_a_good_mother" invisible="1"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <footer attrs="{'invisible': [('id','!=',False)]}">
                        <button name="create_child" string="Create" type="object"
                            class="oe_highlight" />
                        or
                        <button string="Discard" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="action_child_create_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Create child</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">child</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="child_create_form_view" />
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>
        <record id="res_partner_test_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.test.form</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base_location.view_partner_form" />
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='website']" position="after">
                    <button name="%(test.action_child_create_form)d"
                        string="Create child" type="action"
                        class="oe_highlight oe_edit_only" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: I never encounter such problem and I created plenty of `Many2one` fields pointing to records that the user creating the "child" records doesn't have write rights to.
Do you have any computed or related fields on the mother class that this may trigger?

Comment: You are right @LudwikTrammer, I have overwritten the `write` method of **Mother**, to check if it was called and show which values were passed to it, and I have found that when I create a child, an attribute of **Mother** (other one different from `child_ids` -obviously, because as I wrote above it did not exist-) is trying to be modified, so that is the actual problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @LudwikTrammer I have found the origin of the problem, it is a related field. **Child** model has an attribute named `has_a_good_mother`, which is a related field pointing to the field of **Mother** model named `is_a_good_mother`. When I create I child, `write` method of **Mother** is called, and here, the dictionary of the attributes to update (`vals`) has only `is_a_good_mother`.

Comment: Is this a stored related field? Removing the stored status (if possible) may help.

Comment: No, this related field is not being stored in the database. May be the problem is the way in which the child is created. For some reasons, I had to create manually a wizard to add children. This wizard has a footer with two buttons made by me, *Add child* and *Cancel*. *Add child* calls a method of **Child** model made by me too, `add_child`. This method only returns `'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'`, but magically it is calling ORM `create` method of **Child**!!, so I had not to do anything more, I do not know why.

Comment: The "magic" is normal. When one click on a button in an Odoo form (including wizards) the objects is first saved and then the method associated with the button is executed. Is `is_a_good_mother` a computed field? Is it stored?

Comment: Thank you @LudwikTrammer, I did not know that. I found the field which is calling `write` ORM method of **Mother** when creating a child. Model `Child` has another field named `has_a_good_mother`. This field is a related field pointing to `mother_id.is_a_good_mother`. If I declare `has_a_good_mother` as a normal boolean (related to nothing), then when creating a new child, the `write` method of **Mother** is not called. Why?

Comment: I don't see the exact code, so it is hard for me to comment, you may want to read up on `compute_sudo=True` option.

Comment: I've tried `related_sudo` and `compute_sudo`, but same result. Even so, thank you very much, I did not know about those and it is great to learn new options of Odoo. I pasted my code, if it helps to find the problem.