# How to manage related fields and permissions in Odoo 8?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

This question started here: [How to manage security with One2many fields in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590964/how-to-manage-security-with-one2many-fields-in-odoo). But now, I have simplified the problem and the question is not the same one.

The environment and the problem are the same:

```
class mother(models.Model):
    _name = 'mother'

    name = fields.Char(string='Name', size=64, required=True)
    is_a_good_mother = fields.Boolean(string='Is a good mother?')

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        _logger.info('I DO NOT KNOW WHY WHEN CREATING A CHILD THIS ORM '
                     'METHOD IS BEING EXECUTED, RECEIVING THE KEY '
                     'is_a_good_mother')
        return super(mother, self).write(vals)


class child(models.Model):
    _name = 'child'

    mother_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mother',
                                string='Mother', ondelete='cascade')
    has_a_good_mother = fields.Boolean(
        string='Does the child have a good mother?',
        related='mother_id.is_a_good_mother',
        related_sudo=True)
```

I have a menu option which opens a form of **Child**. This form is auto-generated by Odoo.

**The problem**

I have an user who can create and modify children, but not mothers. When this user creates the child, a security error raises telling that the user belongs to a group which cannot modify the **Mother** model. This is due to the line `related='mother_id.is_a_good_mother'`, if I remove it, and the I create a new child, the ORM `write` method of **Mother** is not called.

So if **B** has a related child pointing to any field of **A**, and you create a new record of **B**, ORM `write` method of **A** is called.

I have a security group **my_group**, with `read 1 create 1 write 1 unlink 1` in **B** and `read 1 create 0 write 0 unlink 0` in **A**. As an user of this group cannot write **A**, he gets an error when creating a **B** record.

How can I avoid this error? I have tried with `related_sudo=True`, but it did not work, may be I did not use it well.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does a form used for creating the child contains the "has_a_good_mother" field? If so is the field read-only or not?

Comment: Yes, it does, and it is not readonly.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer That was the problem! I had to set the related field to readonly, otherwise the ORM `write` method is called. Put your comment as an answer and I will set it as correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A related field value is stored in the original field of the "mother" object. So when you try to change it on the "child" object, that's where Odoo updates it behind the scenes. If the user making the change doesn't have a permission to change the "mother" object, an exception will be raised.

You need to make sure that users who don't have permissions to change the target object can't set/change the value of related fields pointing to the object. You can do this for example by making it readonly (`readonly=True`).